# Dynamic Form with Nested Accordion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, accordion, dynamic-forms

I am making n dynamic form within nested accordion.
My question is, how can I make input field inside the generated accordion that contains dynamic form.

I will describe my accordion.
Parent accordion is Level, then content area, pisa framework, children of pisa framework is topic, then the topic has another children sub-topic, then sub-topic has a children course skill and course title.

It is a nested accordion with dynamic form.
I can make multiple sub-topics from 1 topic. I can make multiple topics from 1 pisa framework. and in sub-topics i can create multiple course skill and title.

[Level up to Sub-Topic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtYvv.png)

I can generate multiple Course Skill and the same with Course Title.

I can generate multiple Sub Topics, and Multiple Topics.

[Topic up to Course Skill and Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7Ov.png)

On the first run, with no additional sub-topics. I can run and add multiple course skill and course title. But when I add new sub topics, then on that generated sub-topics I have the same button that can add new course skill and course title, I cannot create course skill and title inside that generated sub-topics.

Can anyone help me.

This is my code for html and javascript. I used jquery

I expect to happen is, when I create new sub-topics and click the button that can add additional input field for course skill and course title. I am newbie, but I think this dynamic form will help me to move forward that's why I add some of it on my feature.

I am using Laravel and blade templating language.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Mathayog | Skills Map</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is the Content Creator Skills Map Creation <br><br>
    <form action="#" method="POST" style="height: 100%;">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="curriculumLead_id" value="{{ $curriculumLead_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_id" value="{{ $admin_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="contentCreator_id" value="{{ $admin_id }}">
        <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
            <div class="accordion-item" style="border: 1px solid #ccc ">
                <h2 class="accordion-header">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                      Level
                    </button>
                </h2>
              <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    {{-- Level Accordion --}}
                    <br><input type="text" name="level" placeholder="Please input Level" class="form-control"><br>
                    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExampleOne">
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOneOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOneOne">
                                    Content Area
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                            <div id="flush-collapseOneOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExampleOne">
                                <div class="accordion-body">
                                    {{-- Content Area Accordion --}}
                                    <br><input type="text" name="content_area" placeholder="Please input Content Area" class="form-control"><br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="accordion-item">
                            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOneTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOneTwo">
                                    PISA Framework
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                            <div id="flush-collapseOneTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExampleOne">
                                <div class="accordion-body">
                                    {{-- PISA Framework Accordion --}}
                                    <br><input type="text" name="pisa_framework" placeholder="Please input PISA Framework" class="form-control"><br>
                                    <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExampleTwo">
                                        <div class="accordion-item">
                                            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOneOneTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOneOneTwo">
                                                  Topic
                                                </button>
                                            </h2>
                                          <div id="flush-collapseOneOneTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExampleTwo">
                                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                                {{-- Topic Accordion --}}
                                                <br><input type="text" name="topic[]" placeholder="Please input Topic" class="form-control"><br>
                                                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="parentAccordion0 show_sub_topic">
                                                    <div class="accordion-item" id="show_sub_topic">
                                                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#subTopicFlushCollapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="subTopicFlushCollapse0">
                                                                Sub Topic
                                                            </button>
                                                        </h2>
                                                        <div id="subTopicFlushCollapse0" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#parentAccordion0">
                                                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                                                {{-- Sub Topic Accordion --}}
                                                                <br><input type="text" name="sub_topic[]" placeholder="Please input Sub Topic" class="form-control"><br>
                                                                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="courseAccordion0">
                                                                    <div class="accordion-item">
                                                                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                                                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#skillFlushCollapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="skillFlushCollapse0">
                                                                                Course Skill
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        </h2>
                                                                        <div id="skillFlushCollapse0" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#courseAccordion0">
                                                                            <div class="col mt-4">
                                                                                <button id="add_course_skill" class="btn btn-warning mb-3 add_more_course_skill">Additional Course Skill</button>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_skill">
                                                                                {{-- Course Skill Accordion --}}
                                                                                <div class="col">
                                                                                    <input name="course_skill[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Skill">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="col">
                                                                                    <button id="remove_course_skill"  class="btn btn-danger mb-3 remove_course_skill">Remove Course Skill</button>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        {{-- <input type="text" name="course_skill[]" placeholder="Please input Course Skill" class="form-control"> --}}
                                                                        {{-- <button id="add_course_skill" class="btn btn-danger add_more_course_skill" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px">Add Course Skill</button> --}}
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="accordion-item">
                                                                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                                                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#titleFlushCollapse0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="titleFlushCollapse0">
                                                                                Course Title
                                                                            </button>
                                                                        </h2>
                                                                        <div id="titleFlushCollapse0" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#courseAccordion0">
                                                                            <div class="col mt-4">
                                                                                <button id="add_course_skill" class="btn btn-warning mb-3 add_more_course_title">Additional Course Title</button>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_title">
                                                                                {{-- Course Title Accordion --}}
                                                                                <div class="col">
                                                                                    <input name="course_title[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Title">
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="col">
                                                                                    <button id="remove_course_title" class="btn btn-danger mb-3 remove_course_title">Remove Course Title</button>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <button id="add_sub_topic" class="btn btn-success add_more_sub_topic" style="margin-top: 15px">Add Sub-Topic</button>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button id="add_topic" class="btn btn-info add_more_topic" style="margin-top: 15px">Add Topic</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-top: 15px">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".add_more_course_skill").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#show_input_skill").prepend(`
                <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_skill">
                    {{-- Added Course Skill Accordion --}}
                    <div class="col">
                        <input name="course_skill[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Skill">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button id="remove_course_skill" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger remove_course_skill">Remove Course Skill</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `);
            });
            $(".add_more_course_title").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#show_input_title").prepend(`
                <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_title">
                    {{-- Course Title Accordion --}}
                    <div class="col">
                        <input name="course_title[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Title">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <button id="remove_course_title" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mb-3 remove_course_title">Remove Course Title</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `);
            });
            let subTopicCounter = 0;
            $(".add_more_sub_topic").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                subTopicCounter++;
                const parentAccordionID = `parentAccordion${subTopicCounter}`;
                const subTopicFlushCollapseID = `subTopicFlushCollapse${subTopicCounter}`;
                const courseAccordionID = `courseAccordion${subTopicCounter}`;
                const skillFlushCollapseID = `skillFlushCollapse${subTopicCounter}`;
                const titleFlushCollapseID = `titleFlushCollapse${subTopicCounter}`;
                

                $("#show_sub_topic").prepend(`
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="${parentAccordionID} show_sub_topic">
                    <div class="accordion-item" id="show_sub_topic">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#${subTopicFlushCollapseID}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${subTopicFlushCollapseID}">
                                Sub Topic
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="${subTopicFlushCollapseID}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#parentAccordion0">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                {{-- Sub Topic Accordion --}}
                                <br><input type="text" name="sub_topic[]" placeholder="Please input Sub Topic" class="form-control"><br>
                                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="${courseAccordionID}">
                                    <div class="accordion-item">
                                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#${skillFlushCollapseID}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${skillFlushCollapseID}">
                                                Course Skill
                                            </button>
                                        </h2>
                                        <div id="${skillFlushCollapseID}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#${courseAccordionID}">
                                            <div class="col mt-4">
                                                <button id="add_course_skill" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mb-3 add_more_course_skill">Additional Course Skill</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_skill">
                                                {{-- Course Skill Accordion --}}
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input name="course_skill[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Skill">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <button id="remove_course_skill" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mb-3 remove_course_skill">Remove Course Skill</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        {{-- <input type="text" name="course_skill[]" placeholder="Please input Course Skill" class="form-control"> --}}
                                        {{-- <button id="add_course_skill" class="btn btn-danger add_more_course_skill" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px">Add Course Skill</button> --}}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="accordion-item">
                                        <h2 class="accordion-header">
                                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#${titleFlushCollapseID}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="${titleFlushCollapseID}">
                                                Course Title
                                            </button>
                                        </h2>
                                        <div id="${titleFlushCollapseID}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#${courseAccordionID}">
                                            <div class="col mt-4">
                                                <button id="add_course_skill" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mb-3 add_more_course_title">Additional Course Title</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="accordion-body row g-2" id="show_input_title">
                                                {{-- Course Title Accordion --}}
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <input name="course_title[]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Title">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <button id="remove_course_title" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mb-3 remove_course_title">Remove Course Title</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `)
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code, but all I get is [this](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/PoXvRJR). Looks like the CSS is missing and it looks that you're also using some kind of templating software?

Comment: Hi, I edit the question again, I include the whole code instead. From HTML up to the Script. This should work on normal HTML file if you copy and paste it.

Comment: It's better, but I don't think it does what you say it does. Does one have to press "Submit" to create a new "skill" or "title"? When I press "Add Topic" everything I had done disappears. Perhaps that is the problem you're having? I still feel something off. Especially the `{{ .... }}` thingies look suspicious.

Comment: Can I contact you in whatsapp sir? 09155089258 so I can show you when it is working.